# Not able to log the axis1internal flow

Tags: axis

I created dynamic web project in eclipse. I am not able to pass commons-logginf file to factory . please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

I got resolution . I am able to log the Axis Internal Flow. src/commons-logging.properties : org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger inputs to Log4JLogger class is below properties file. classes folder in web-inf :web-inf/classes/log4j.properties log4j.properties : log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CONSOLE log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=DEBUG log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=- %m%n log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=axis.log log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n